# man kaio: No manual entry for kaio

Tags: solaris, truss

I trussed a process, and they are lines as below. And I want to know the definition of kaio, but there is no manual entry for kaio, so whether can I get the definition?

```
/1:     kaio(AIOWRITE, 259, 0x3805B2A00, 8704, 0x099C9E000755D3C0) = 0
/1:     kaio(AIOWRITE, 259, 0x380CF9200, 14336, 0x099CC0000755D5B8) = 0
/1:     kaio(AIOWRITE, 259, 0x381573600, 8704, 0x099CF8000755D7B0) = 0
/1:     kaio(AIOWRITE, 259, 0x381ACA600, 8192, 0x099D1A000755D9A8) = 0
/1:     kaio(AIOWAIT, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFD620)               = 4418032576
/1:             timeout: 600.000000 sec
/1:     kaio(AIOWAIT, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFD620)               = 4418033080
/1:             timeout: 600.000000 sec
/1:     kaio(AIOWAIT, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFD620)               = 4418033584
/1:             timeout: 600.000000 sec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [an article](http://sunsite.uakom.sk/sunworldonline/swol-07-1998/swol-07-insidesolaris.html) about it:

> What kaio does, as the name implies, is implement async I/O inside the kernel rather than in user-land via user threads. The I/O queue is created and managed in the operating system. The basic sequence of events is as follows: When an application calls aioread(3) or aiowrite(3), the corresponding library routine is entered. Once entered, the library first tries to process the request via kaio. A kaio initialization routine is executed, which creates a "cleanup" thread, which is intended to ensure that there are no remaining memory segments that have been allocated but not freed during the async I/O process. Once that's complete, kaio is called, at which point a test is made to determine if kaio is supported for the requested I/O.
>
> Kaio is implemented as a loadable kernel module, /kernel/sys/kaio, and is loaded the first time an async I/O is called. You can determine if the module is loaded or not with modinfo(1M):

```
fawlty> modinfo | grep kaio 
105 608c4000   2efd 178   1  kaio (kernel Async I/O) 
fawlty>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer:

it's defined in file /usr/include/sys/syscall.h

```
#define SYS_kaio                178
        /*
         * subcodes:
         *      aioread(...)    :: kaio(AIOREAD, ...)
         *      aiowrite(...)   :: kaio(AIOWRITE, ...)
         *      aiowait(...)    :: kaio(AIOWAIT, ...)
         *      aiocancel(...)  :: kaio(AIOCANCEL, ...)
         *      aionotify()     :: kaio(AIONOTIFY)
         *      aioinit()       :: kaio(AIOINIT)
         *      aiostart()      :: kaio(AIOSTART)
         *      see 
         */
```